# Отображение свойств только на tablet и desktop

Tags: css, media-queries

```
<style>
.text {
............
}
<style>
<div class="text">Text</div>
```

Каким должен быть media-запрос, чтобы к div не применялись CSS-свойства на экранах <480?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужен такой медиа-запрос:

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .text {
    \* свойства:значения *\ 
  }
}
```